# Can we still able to use activity in Xamarin Project

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

This is my first time doing Xamarin Form or PCL. In Xamarin Form, I can see there are few controls and pages available. Can we still able to design android layout in resource folder and called setContentView in onCreate function.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can - you're fully able to [mix-and-match](https://www.xamarin.com/forms#mix-and-match) any Xamarin.Classic code within Xamarin.Forms . You'll have to create the Android design inside the `.Droid` folder and understand that this functionality will only be available on Android.

To make it work, you'll have to create a Custom Renderer. Forms will use this Custom Renderer to embed the Xamarin.Classic code inside the Forms application. I suggest you to read [the documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) about this subject, or check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQbe_YAgdog).

Take note that - if you're doing this - you're not fully using the power of Xamarin.Forms. Forms is created in such a way it should be easy to create cross-platform apps with loads of re-use. Creating Custom Renderers will make it work for one platform, but not magically for the other. The `OnCreate` functionality is something is available in [the Xamarin.Forms lifecycle](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/app-lifecycle/) as well, which does work cross-platform.

I hope this guides you to the right direction - good luck!

Comment: When I look at xamarin form even though they have some controls but there are alot of controls on platform that form doesn't provide. I want to use ViewPager on android. The similar version in form is Carousel Page but it looks like it will load all the pages at once. For viewpager, it only show the one visible.

Comment: I totally understand that, but if you want to use more of the power of the platforms themselves, Xamarin.Forms might not be the best option and you should just go with Xamarin.Classic . Check out the [approach](https://www.xamarin.com/forms#choose-an-approach) on when to choose for Forms or Classic.